# Direct addressing without segment in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

The encoding of memory operands with the SIB-byte allows a ›none register‹ for index as well as base. So this should be a valid instruction:

**03 04 25 10 32 54 76** – `add eax, dword [ 0x76543210 ]`

The address should be calculated like this: 1·0+0+0x76543210 and is not based on any segment register.
In a flat memory this should not change anything, but is this different from `add eax, dword ds:0x76543210`, if `ds` is not zero?

Comment: `ds` is the implicit segment, it's the same as typing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 16 and 32 bit operation modes, a SIB byte indicating no base and no index (ie. `04 +r 25`) simply encodes a 32 bit address, just as the modr/m byte `05 +r` does. This does not affect segmentation, `ds` is used to add a segment base address in both cases.

In long mode (64 bit mode), the modr/m byte `05 +r` indicates a `rip` (resp. `eip`) relative address whereas `04 +r 25` indicates an absolute address. For example:

```
8b 05 XX XX XX XX       is mov eax, [rip+XXXXXXXX]
8b 04 25 XX XX XX XX    is mov eax, [XXXXXXXX]
```